# Convert Ubuntu Server 20.10 to lts version

Tags: server

I want to install Canonical Livepatch Service. I downloaded the latest version of ubuntu but didn't know that i cannot install Livepatch Service, I need LTS version.
Is it possible to convert to lts?

Comment: There is no "official" way to downgrade. I think it would be easier to reinstall 20.04 than try to downgrade.

Comment: You can re-install, as Ubuntu *release-upgrade* tool upgrade to later releases, so to go to the LTS using Ubuntu tools, you'll have to wait till 21.04 is released, upgrade to that, wait till 21.10 is released, upgrade to that, wait till 22.04 is released & finally upgrade to the LTS release.

Comment: @guiverc Until then, what about the updates? What time do I need to update it? `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: 20.10 means the 2020-October release, 21.04 means the 2021-April release, so you *release-upgrade* every 6 months (servers are often delayed a little to ensure stability; let others discover the problems etc).. Upgrades can occur anytime, and `sudo apt full-upgrade` performs all upgrades; `apt-get upgrade` only installs some (see `man` pages for clue, differences exist between `apt upgrade` & `apt-get upgrade` too.. but not between `apt-get dist-upgrade` and `apt full-upgrade`)